Confusion about finding a covering space for $\langle a^2, (ab)^4, b^2\rangle \leq \pi_1 (\mathbb S ^ 1 \vee \mathbb S ^ 1)$ (Hatcher 1.3.12)
I am confused about the covering space of the wedge sum of two circles that corresponds to a subgroup $\langle a^2, (ab)^4, b^2\rangle$ (reminiscent of $D_4$) of the fundamental group of the base space $\pi_1(\mathbb S ^ 1 \vee \mathbb S ^ 1)$.
As I recall from Seifart van Kampen applied to a graph, the number of generators for the group should correspond to the total number of edges in the graph minus the number of edges contained in a spanning tree. There would be 16 edges in total and 7 edges in the spanning tree, leaving us with 9 generators.
If we write $E = E_1 \cup E_2$ and $E_0 = E_1 \cap E_2$, we can graphically apply Seifart van Kampen to confirm the result.

In any case, I believe that $\pi_1(E)\cong \langle \gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_9 \rangle$.
What I failed to understand is that the 9 generators of the fundamental group for the covering space could produce three generators for the subgroup  given that the covering monomorphism $p_*$ is inherently injective.
There must be some obvious detail that I am overlooking because in all of the other examples provided in Hatcher, it appeared that the number of elements in the subgroup was directly related to the number of loops provided in the covering space. This solution would appear to contradict the trend that I had observed, so I imagine that some of the additional symmetries in the covering space would “cancel” the extra number of generators. Or, is it possible that $p_{*}$ is still injective but some of the generators for $p_*(\gamma_1)$ through $p_*(\gamma_9)$ were redundant and could just be removed from the final group presentation? I do not know how either of these cancellations would occur, and I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could expound upon the proper procedure for calculating the covering space for a subgroup with high order terms (e.g., $(ab)^4$ or $a^n b^m$). Additionally, if anyone had suggestions for other reading materials besides Hatcher, possibly lecture notes or homework assignments, I would be very thankful.

The picture you have drawn is not the covering space for the subgroup $H = \langle a^2,(ab)^4,b^2\rangle < \langle a,b \rangle=G$.
Instead, your pictures is the covering space for the normal subgroup $H^G$, which does indeed have rank $9$ as you have shown. You can also use your picture to show that $H^G$ has index $8$ inside $G$ (because the covering map has degree $8$). Furthermore, this is a regular covering map, and its deck transformation group  --- which is isomorphic to the quotient group $G / H^G$ --- is an order $8$ dihedral group.
One way you can see that your picture is not the right covering space for $H$ is that there is a closed loop for the group element $b^{-1}a^2b$ which is not contained in subgroup $H$, even though that element is obviously contained in $H^G$.
Here is a description of the correct covering space for $H$, obtained by altering your first picture. In your picture there are three important loops at the base point (labelled $e_0$?) namely:

The $a^2$ loop
The $b^2$ loop
The $(ab)^4$ loop, which is the "outer octagon" of your picture. It's first edge labelled $a$ is the same as the first $a$ on the $a^2$ loop. And its last edge labelled $b$ is the same as the second $b$ on the $b^2$ loop.

Keep the union of those three loops. But throw away the other 6 edges of the picture. These are the 6 edges of the inner octagon that do not lie on either the $a^2$ loop attached to the base point nor the $b^2$ loop attached to the base point.
The graph you get after throwing away those 6 edges is unfortunately not yet a covering space. To make it a covering space without altering the fundamental group it represents, you will have to add some infinite trees at 6 of the vertices. For instance, let $v \ne e_0$ denote the other vertex of the $a^2$ loop. At $v$ the graph has an $a$ edge pointing away from $v$, an $a$ edge pointing towards $v$, and a $b$ edge pointing away from $v$. One more edge must be attached to $v$, namely a $b$ edge pointing towards $v$. But now, at the opposite endpoint of that new edge, three more edges have to be attached; and at their opposite endpoints three more edges each have to be attached, and so on; continuing inductively, you end up attaching an infinite tree to $v$.
Once you are all done, you will indeed have a rank 3 graph: those infinite trees that you attached do not contribute to the fundamental group. Also, you can see from this covering map that the subgroup $H$ has infinite index in $G$, because the covering map has infinite degree.
